# Can I use an AutoRun.inf file on a USB drive?

Tags: hta, autorun, inf

I tried to run autorun.inf that I created but I cant get it to work. Is it even possible to do so or is it just for CD's. If not is there an alternative to do this or an equivalent?

This is all that I want it to do:

```
open=Launcher-Plus.hta
icon=Launcher-Plus.ico
```

Comment: http://blog.shankarganesh.com/2007/08/11/how-to-autorun-programs-from-usb-flash-drive/

Comment: Thanks man, this sort of worked, but it was only the label part that worked, the icon changed but it was a white page instead of my custom ico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autorun.inf got blocked from all the new released Windows system after the massive removable device viruses took advantage of it. So the short answer is NO you can't do it anymore, not even on CD

Comment: I am running Windows 8.1 and what admdrew said somewhat worked. It changed the label of the drive but the icon wont work and the program wont start. Could that be caused by what you are saying?

Comment: @user3184214 autorun is turned off by default, http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/change-autoplay-settings#1TC=windows-7 check this to see how to turn it on

Comment: Could I possibly use some sort of script? Like VBS or Batch?

Comment: @user3184214 Whats the motivation behind this?

Comment: I am making a usb portable software launcher and development kit. I would like to have some sort of file in the root of the drive to automatically start the program when the usb is plugged in, change the drive name, hopefully change the drive letter (but not mandatory), and change the icon. If there is some kind of alternative that can do that I'm all for it. And I checked out that link buy the way and that is not exactly what I am looking for. Those options applies to all media that fits the description on any usb drive, I need something aimed just for that drive.

Comment: @user3184214 note that the user still have to turn the option on in-order for autorun to work. But this is really a dangerous thing to have the user to do. So basically the answer here is that you can't do it automatically anymore for anything beyond windows XP. You will have to ask the user to start the program by themselves.

Comment: Okay, this is all I needed to know. Thanks a lot steve.